# Emojis displaying in Android API 25 but not in 17

Tags: android

I'm doing an application where the user choose a language and I use the name of the country and a flag and it looks very nice, but when running in old phones around API 17 the flag emojis don't display, one solution could be to add a imageView and add the flags as images but I'm using it in different places and it would be really good If I could just use text.

Anyway the quick solution I'm using is the following:

```
public String getName()
{
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        return this.mName;
    else
        return this.mName + " " + this.mFlag;
}
```

[image API 17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pnSo.png)

[image API 25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqrtO.png)

Answer (score 0):

The emoji's you're requesting to show simply don't exist on older Android versions.

So there is nothing to display, which should cause a small blue rectangle with a cross over it to be displayed instead (this is the "error" that is shown when the emoji couldn't be shown).

Sadly there is nothing you can do to fix this.

Comment: Setting a custom font with those emojis would fix it.  But you'd need to find it and bundle it with your app.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if there were some easy solution, I think I'll use images instead and no in this case there is no small blue rectangle, in my case there are two letter instead of the flag, here is why https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTzp76JXsoY =)